# Overwriting array of structs in C

Tags: c, memory, struct

I'm trying to pass a pointer to an array of structs to a function. Then have the function create its own array of structures, populate it with data and then overwright the the old array with the new array.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with occurring when I try to overwrite the memory. I think that I could be either using the wrong method to overwrite the memory(should I be using the memory functions?) or I might be trying to overwrite the wrong thing. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be extremely thankful; I've been pulling the hair out of my head for like three hours now.

Struct:

```
typedef struct
{
        char command;
        int argc;
        char* argv[];
}cmd;
```

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    [... irrelevant code]
    cmd cmdv[count];
    cmd* cmdv_ptr = &cmdv[0];
    dissectCmd(cmdstr, cmdv_ptr);
    printf("%i", cmdv[0].argc);
    return 0;
}

void dissectCmd(char* str, cmd* cmdv)
{
    [... irrelevant code]
    cmd cmds[count];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cmd next;
        next.command = 'u';
        next.argc = 100;
        cmds[i] = next;
    }
    cmdv = cmds;
}
```

Comment: cmd cmds[count] is a local VLA array, isn't it? even if you pass cmd **cmdv and *cmdv = cmds, it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You're not overwriting the memory -- the statement `cmdv = cmds` just copies the pointer (making cmdv point at cmds.)  If you want to actually copy the memory, you need `memcpy(cmdv, cmds, count * sizeof(cmd));`

Comment: ... or you could just do `cmdv[i] = next;` in the loop and do away with `cmds` entirely.

Comment: @caf, could work, but only if there will never be any premature returns or exceptions inside that loop. Otherwise it could result in a partially overwritten array which isn't always desired.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure about this, but try declaring

> void dissectCmd(char* str, cmd* cmdv)

as

> void dissectCmd(char* str, cmd** cmdv)

changing

> cmdv = cmds;

to

> (*cmdv) = &cmds;

and changing current call from main which is now

> dissectCmd(cmdstr, cmdv_ptr);

to

> dissectCmd(cmdstr, &cmdv_ptr);

also, when you do this, you loose the address to the old array completely, creating a memory leak. unless you already free that memory in your second *[... irrelevant code]* passage :)

Comment: right, this won't work.. you should look at chris dodd's solution. my version might work though if you change printf("%i", cmdv[0].argc); to printf("%i", (*cmdv_ptr)[0].argc); D:

Comment: This will leave cmdv_ptr in main dangling, pointing at the memory for the local cmds in dissectCmd's stack frame which was freed when dissectCmd returned

Comment: true! i missed the fact that the cmd structs inside dissectCmd wasn't new:ed :(